# Use Apache Cordova to develop OS X application

Tags: windows, macos, cross-platform, visual-studio-cordova, apache-cordova

I'm wondering, if it's possible to develop an OS X application using Apache Cordova. There is only iOS mentioned on their site. But I'm currently evaluating a possibility to create a cross-platform app for Windows, OS X and than mobile platforms using Visual Studio.

Your suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Visual Studio doesn't provide built-in support for Mac OS X development, using Cordova. However, when you use the Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova (Visual Studio TACO) you're really working with a standard Apache Cordova project. This means that you could use a project like the following which adds support for Mac OS X as a platform:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-osx

To use this, you'd need to work with the Cordova command line (e.g. `npm install -g cordova`) tools. You would install these tools, change into the directory for your Cordova project from Visual Studio, and then you should be able to follow the steps on that GitHub repo's [readme](https://github.com/apache/cordova-osx#create-your-project). There are caveats for now - this solution only supports full-screen "kiosk" apps on Mac OS X, rather than building a fully integrated desktop app with features like a menu bar.

Comment: Thank you, Jordan. I'll take a look on it.